# Laravel 5.3 API bangla

Tags: mysql, json, laravel-5, unicode

How to insert and show Bangla characters using Laravel 5.3 API and MySQL? The database data and the json preview are shown in the following pictures.

[database preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5q8IC.png)

[json preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89o64.png)

Answer (score 0):

The database preview show Mojibake; see [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

The json preview show Unicode codes -- see `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` in PHP's Documentation, [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [Predefined Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php).